# django custom command complains AssertionError: ForeignKey(None) is invalid. why

Tags: django

I've followed django custom command tutorial, the link is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

My working directory looks like this:

```
myapps/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/  
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            my_command.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

My code looks like this:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print '=========='
        self.stdout.write('Successfully closed poll ttt')
```

When I run the command manage.py my_command, I got the following errors,

```
  File "D:/ERP\apps\person\salary\models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Salarys(models.Model):
  File "D:/ERP\apps\person\salary\models.py", line 14, in Salarys
    Unit = models.ForeignKey(Units, verbose_name = u'def_unit, on_delete = models.PROTECT) 
  File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 910, in __init__
    assert isinstance(to, basestring), "%s(%r) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string %r" % (self.__class__.__name__, to, RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT)
AssertionError: ForeignKey(None) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

Obviously, the first parameter of ForeignKey is my model Units, how do I silence the compiler's complaint?

ps: my model looks like this:
my model looks like this now.

```
class Salarys(models.Model):
    '''
    describe : salary table
    author : liyang 2013-1-23
    '''
    User = models.ForeignKey(Users, verbose_name = u'account', on_delete = models.PROTECT) 
    Unit = models.ForeignKey(Units, verbose_name = u'def_unit', on_delete = models.PROTECT, null=True) 
    yy = models.IntegerField(u'year)
    mm = models.IntegerField(u'month')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users_salarys'

class Units(models.Model):
    '''
    describe : def unit model
    author : liyang 2012-12-4 11:45
    '''
    name = models.CharField(u'name',max_length = 20) 
    cname = models.CharField(u'company name',max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True) 
    aname = models.CharField(u'company short cut',max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)         
    telephone = models.CharField(u'contact',max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)         
    website = models.CharField(u'website',max_length = 25, blank = True, null = True)         
    address = models.CharField(u'address',max_length = 50, blank = True, null = True)         
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'units'
```

....

the strange things are

1: User foreignkey does not make any troubles while Unit does...

2: my web server can be run without any problem while the command line can not be run...

Comment: Your error is coming from models.py and doesn't seem to have anything to do with your custom command. Can you share your models?

Comment: I believe that for your foreign key you'd need to specify null=True attribute.

Comment: thanks Sidharth Shah, i add null=True in model, the complain does not go away...

Comment: You are missing a single quote after `u'def_unit` on the exact same line pointed by the error message

Comment: thanks Daniel Aronne, the problem is not here, i made a mistake when copying and pasting my code...the error is still there

Comment: Put your class `Units` declaration before class `Salarys`. In your class `Salarys` you are referencing class `Units` before actually declaring it.

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Units` should come before your class `Salarys`:

```
class Units(models.Model):
    ...

class Salarys(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, verbose_name = u'account', on_delete = models.PROTECT) 
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Units, verbose_name = u'def_unit', on_delete = models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

One more recommendation: it's a best practice to name your model in singular. Django will automatically "pluralize" them. If Django fails to pluralize the class name properly, you can specify your own plural by adding the following to the models Meta:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "salaries"
```

Comment: how could i determined which model comes first, if Units and Salarys reside in defferent folder

Comment: If `Units` and `Salarys` are in different `models.py` files, then you need to make sure you import your `Units` models in the file where you have the `Salarys` model.